# UnknownError: Fail to find the dnn implementation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I don't know what happened, but when I am trying to train a model on Keras I am getting this error.

```
UnknownError:    Fail to find the dnn implementation.
     [[{{node CudnnRNN}}]]
     [[sequential/lstm/PartitionedCall]] [Op:__inference_train_function_8758]

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function -> train_function
```

Here's my sequential model:

```
def prepare_sequences(notes, n_vocab, seq_len):
    """ Prepare the sequences used by the Neural Network """
    sequence_length = seq_len

    names = sorted(set(item for item in notes))
    note_to_int = dict((note, number) for number, note in enumerate(names))

    network_input = []
    network_output = []

    # create input sequences and the corresponding outputs
    for i in range(0, len(notes) - sequence_length, 1):
        sequence_in = notes[i:i + sequence_length]
        sequence_out = notes[i + sequence_length]
        network_input.append([note_to_int[char] for char in sequence_in])
        network_output.append(note_to_int[sequence_out])

    n_patterns = len(network_input)

    # reshape the input into a format compatible with LSTM layers
    network_input = numpy.reshape(network_input, (n_patterns, sequence_length, 1))
    # normalize input
    network_input = network_input / float(n_vocab)

    network_output = np_utils.to_categorical(network_output)

    return (network_input, network_output)

def create_network(network_input, n_vocab, LSTM_node_count, Dropout_count):
    """ create the structure of the neural network """
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(
        LSTM_node_count,
        input_shape=(network_input.shape[1], network_input.shape[2]),
        recurrent_dropout= 0,
        return_sequences=True
    ))
    model.add(LSTM(
        LSTM_node_count, 
        return_sequences=True, 
        recurrent_dropout= 0,))
    model.add(LSTM(LSTM_node_count))
    model.add(BatchNorm())
    model.add(Dropout(Dropout_count))
    model.add(Dense(256))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(BatchNorm())
    model.add(Dropout(Dropout_count))
    model.add(Dense(n_vocab))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')

    return model

def train(model, network_input, network_output, epoch, batchsize):
    """ train the neural network """
    filepath = "trained_weights/" + "weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{loss:.4f}-bigger.hdf5"
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath,
        monitor='loss',
        verbose=0,
        save_best_only= True,
        mode='min'
    )
    callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

    model.fit(network_input, 
              network_output, 
              epochs= epoch,
              batch_size= batchsize, 
              callbacks= callbacks_list)
```

Here's my driver details

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf1
sess = tf1.Session(config=tf1.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))

Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 -> device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1650, pci bus id: 0000:0a:00.0, compute capability: 7.5
```

Nvidia driver and CUDA version.

```
> nvidia-smi
Tue Dec 29 16:16:34 2020
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.89       Driver Version: 460.89       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1650   WDDM  | 00000000:0A:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 30%   37C    P8     4W /  75W |   4048MiB /  4096MiB |      1%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1292    C+G   Insufficient Permissions        N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2184    C+G   ...es.TextInput.InputApp.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2636    C+G   ...me\Application\chrome.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3416    C+G   ...perience\NVIDIA Share.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5676      C   ...ython\Python38\python.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      6352    C+G   ...artMenuExperienceHost.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      6784    C+G   ...w5n1h2txyewy\SearchUI.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     10148      C   ...thon\Python38\pythonw.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     11368    C+G   ...8bbwe\Microsoft.Notes.exe    N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here is my version details:

```
Tensorflow Version: 2.4.0
Keras Version: 2.4.0

Python: 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Pandas: 1.2.0
scikit-learn: 0.24.0

GPU:
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

I have a different computer with the exact same driver and CUDA version and I am able to run the model normally in the other computer but not this one.

I tried the following solutions provided by other threads and it still didn't work.

```
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)

configproto = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto() 
configproto.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=configproto) 
tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(sess)
```